# My recently asked question does not show up on the active page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, specific-question

[What could make a species evolve downward facing ears?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/95157/what-could-make-a-species-evolve-downward-facing-ears)

This question does not appear on the [active page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) of Worldbuilding.SE. It does not disappear completely and can still be accessed from [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions) when searching for example through the newest questions.

I noticed this happened after I edited my question after posting it within the 5 minutes grace period.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I cannot reproduce this

Your question shows up just fine. Right now it's directly under the question "Inorganic alien consciousness [on hold]" at 14<sup>th</sup> position in the active questions.

Other than that: if any post on a question, either the question itself or any of the answers, are edited your question will appear at the top. This also happens if for example someone answers your question. Currently the last tracked activity is my answer 4 hours ago. But it will take a minute or two when there is new activity before it is shown when reloading the page, although people who currently have the page open and are not using an Ad-Blocker should receive a message indicating something like "1 post with activity". Just wait a bit and then reload the site.

Comment: Weird. It now shows up in my active page. Might've been a cache issue, since I restarted my laptop, and now I used app. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, this is caching -- *right* after you post (or edit), it might not show up for you -- but it will for anybody else, and will for you in a minute or two.  Also, if you use the browser back button to go back to the questions list, that won't be updated until you refresh, same as if you use back to get back to a question you just voted on (and your vote isn't there).

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, new questions take up to 15 minutes to show in "Active" page. Usually less, but it happens, it was happening all the years I'm on Stack Exchange. I admit, I no longer care, but I remember it was frustrating when it happened to me for the first time.